# Issue with .NET LINQ query preparation

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, entity-framework, linq

We are having an issue in linq query. In select query multiple tables are associated with joins. Where record filters were applied on join section.

This query was running fine and giving proper result within time since past 8 to 9 months. 
Suddenly it took time around 2 minute to retrieve the record with the same join and consuming 99% CPU.

This query is being used always while user login so its sure that it was running fine in past till issue moment.
Can any one help why this issue occurred suddenly?

```
var entityList = (from x in db.TableA
    join y in db.TableB on x.Id equals y.TableC.TableAId into g
    from d in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where d.EndDateTime == null &&
          (d == null || d.TableE.PersonID == personId) &&
          x.EndDateTime == null &&
          d.TableC.EndDateTime == null &&
          x.TableE.PersonID == personId
    select new
    {
        Col1 = d != null ? d.TableC.TableD.Id : 0,
        Col2 = d != null ? d.TableC.Id : 0,
    }).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: The size of the database may have grown or gotten fragmented.  See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html

Comment: It could be a million things, index problems, disk corruption, network speed etc. You need to dig into this yourself I'm afraid. Start with extracting the query that is being executed and see what it looks like. Run it manually against the database, is it slow there? Check execution plans etc. etc.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the generated `SELECT`, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and the approximate size of the tables.

Comment: @jdweng - Defragmentation does not cause more than a few percent performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

If that framework turns `d == null` into `d = null` instead of `d IS NULL`, that is a serious flaw.

`OR` can hurt performance.  Do you really need the `NULL` option for `d`?  What indexes are there?